# d3.zoom will not zoom

Tags: angular, d3.js, electron

I'm trying to implement the tree view with zoom in D3 with no success.
It displays the Tree but the zoom just won't work. It doesn't respond to any mouse wheel movement for some reason. No compilation errors.

```
 constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.host = D3.select(this.element.nativeElement);
 }
  draw(issue) {
    if (!issue) {
      return;
    }
    var zoom = D3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 10])
      .on("zoom", this.zoomed);

    var nodes = D3.hierarchy(issue, function (d) {
      return d.children;
    });

    nodes = this.treemap(nodes);

    var svg = this.host.append('svg')
      .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
      .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom);
    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
        .call(zoom);
    this.container = svg;

    var link = g.selectAll(".link")
      .data(nodes.descendants().slice(1))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function (d) {
        return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
          + "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.x
          + " " + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.parent.x
          + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
      });

    var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes.descendants())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "node" +
          (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
      })
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      });

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10);

    node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children ? -13 : 13; })
      .style("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });
  }

  zoomed() {
    this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + this.host.event.translate + ")scale(" + this.host.event.scale + ")");
  }
}
```

I'm unsure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(this.host.event.translate)` in `zoomed()` and post the results?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined
    at SVGGElement.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/components/traceability-node/traceability-node.component.ts.TraceabilityNodeComponent.zoomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zoomed()` function needs to get the event from d3, try to

- declare `zoomed` inside the `draw` scope
- attach the zoom event to `g` instead of `svg`
- get the event.transform from d3

  ```
  zoomed() {
      g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
   }
  ```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
    at SVGSVGElement.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/components/traceability-node/traceability-node.component.ts.TraceabilityNodeComponent.zoomed

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be the case. Declaring zoom/pan callbacks outside of the main scope doesn't work so well in my experience. I have update my answer

Comment: Awesome, it works now but the zoom effect is a bit strange, the drag is bumpy and the zoom isn't on mouse point but more of a cornered zoom.
I'm trying to achieve the effect here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

Comment: I donth know the specific of what you want to do, but I'm going to assume that you want the zoom to affect your group `g` and not the entire `svg` in which case it should `g.attr("transform`', ...`

Comment: Sweet, you are right, SVG moved the whole component while G moves only the Tree inside the SVG which is what I originally wanted. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back , I updated my answer for future use.